# How do I change the Dock magnification on Mac OS X using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-elcapitan, hotkeys, automator

I am new to Automator and AppleScript. I see a couple of links about customizing the dock, but they seem to be doing more than I need (or understand). Is there a quick, short way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Dock magnification via AppleScript like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell dock preferences
        set properties to {magnification:true, magnification size:1.5}
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Worked well. Also added keyboard shortcut using an automator service and system preferences. Thanks !